# Exclude categories For Custom post types [Wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress

I have category 1, category 2, category 3, to category 7 and custom post types Gallery, Article, Front Row..

How can we restrict the admin to choose the category for custom post type Gallery to Cat 1, 2 3 only?

```
<?php 
    register_post_type('gallery',
        'taxononmies' => array('category' => array(1, 2, 3))
    );
?>
```